# PDO returning 0 rows on WHERE with enum

Tags: mysql, php, prepared-statement, enum

I am trying to build a query for a report. The report will have a few fields that can be filtered, one of which is a `jobStatus` field, it is an enum.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN property p ON j.propertyID = p.propertyID
LEFT JOIN property_buildings b ON b.buildingID = j.buildingID
LEFT JOIN departments d ON j.dptID = d.dptID
LEFT JOIN jobs_timeframe jt ON j.jobTimeframeID = jt.jobTimeframeID
LEFT JOIN jobs_type t ON j.jobTypeID = t.jobTypeID
LEFT JOIN floors f ON f.floorID = j.floor
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT group_concat(a.assetNo) AS assets, ja.jobID
    FROM jobs_assets ja
    INNER JOIN assets a ON a.assetID = ja.assetID
    GROUP BY jobID
    ORDER BY assetNo ASC
) ja ON ja.jobID = j.jobID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT group_concat(o.obsNo) AS observations, oj.jobID
    FROM observationJobs oj
    INNER JOIN observation o ON o.obsID = oj.obsID
    GROUP BY jobID
    ORDER BY obsNo ASC
) jo ON jo.jobID = j.jobID
WHERE j.ClientID = :clientID AND j.jobStatus = :status
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

Here are my bound parameters:
:clientID => 14,
:status => 'Draft',
:limit => 25,
:offset => 0

If i exclude the `j.jobStatus` it works fine and shows 19 results with a mix of jobStatus' including `Draft`, `Finished` and `Approved` If i include try and filter by `j.jobStatus` at all using PDO i get a successful query but with zero rows (should be 14 rows for `Draft`, 1 for `Approved`, 3 for `Finished` and 1 null)

if i unsafely just put the variable for :status in the query
(like this `WHERE j.ClientID = :clientID AND j.jobStatus = '.$status.' LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset`)
it works fine and shows the 14 expected results. I can not for the life of me figure out why.

The only thing I can think of is it is something to do with it being an enum, but i was under the impression that they are treated as strings for everything except the actual storage.

EDIT:
binding code:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $lim, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $params[':status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':clientID', $params[':clientID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Enable General log temporarily and look for actual query text received by server.

Comment: Edit your question with your PHP PDO binding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the foreach loop i was using to bind the parameters as seen in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144557/php-pdo-bindparam-was-falling-in-a-foreach) on stackoverflow

for anyone who comes across a similar issue in the future the following will fail:

```
foreach($params AS $k => $v){
    $stmt->bindParam($k, $v);
}
```

as bindParam does not actually bind it when you call it, it just binds a link to `$v` so it will always be the last item it the loop. to overcome this, you need to pass the argument by reference as follows:

```
foreach($params AS $k => &$v){
    $stmt->bindParam($k, $v);
}
```

notice the `&` before `$v` in the foreach, cause it to work as expected.